# SQL Management Studio on Windows 7 64Bit

Tags: windows-7, sql, ssms

We're scratching our heads a bit here. We have SQL Server 2000 on our internal systems and I have a new machine.

My old windows XP machine had Mgmt Studio (full version). I have tried to run the SQL 2000 installation disks, but they are not 64 bit so I can't install the tool.

I have downloaded the express version on MS website which has installed OK, but this doesn't allow me to run jobs as it's not a full version.

Where can I find an installation for the full version (64bit) ?

[edit] I am now running windows 7 on my new machine which is where I need to install the mgmt studio![/edit]

Comment: So Management Studio 2000 on WIndows 7? Hm - funny. Sql Server 2000 is ANCIENT.

Comment: Don't use desktop OSes to run SQL servers.  Also, avoid running software after its EOL (which I believe finally expired after far too long in April).

Comment: Don't you mean "Enterprise Manager"? That's what sql server 2000 used.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, dude...

> I have tried to run the SQL 2000 installation disks, but they are not 64 bit so I can't 
>   install the tool.

Ever since MS decided to make 64 bit operating systems, they have been able to run 32 bit software. On my windows 8 - 64 bit - the office still is 32 bit.

Your problem is more: you ask a SQL Server 2000 question which is SO end of life... Have you considered hiring an archeologist helping you?

Otherwise just grab your latest Developer version installer and run it.

Btw., why the heck do you tag that with Windows 7 - you seem to run anything except that version.

Comment: haha - my mistake! I forgot to actually state I am running windows 7 now! By "the latest developer version" do you mean a dev version of sql server? Do I need to download the whole server suite to just get the mgmt studio?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 is not supported on Vista, 7, or server 2008.  (2008 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948680, Win7 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2009/10/23/sql-server-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)

You should download a recent version of SQL Server Express, install only the management tools, and use that to connect to your SQL Server 2000 server (register new server, etc.).  Bear in mind that SSMS may offer you features that the server doesn't support, however.

Also, if your newer version of SSMS is not allowing you to run jobs, make sure you're connecting to a full version of SQL Server instead of the local instance.  It's the express version's server that's hobbled for jobs, not SSMS.  (I use a version of Express' SSMS to run/edit full version's jobs frequently.)  If you need to run jobs locally for development, consider a developer edition.

(I use 2008 SSMS to connect to 2008 Server and 2005 Server, but other people I googled are connecting to 2000.)

Comment: P.S.  2008 Express:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695

2012 Express:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062